# RubyMotion is Not Loading AudioToolbox framework

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

So I was trying to use AudioToolbox with RubyMotion,

1, Added

```
app.frameworks << 'AudioToolbox'
```

in Rakefile,

2, And in one of my simple view controller method, simply added

```
p AudioFileID
```

3, Then rake,

4, Given an error,

```
uninitialized constant RecorderViewController::AudioFileID (NameError)
```

Obviously AudioFileID which in AudioToolbox was not loaded, I tried similar thing in CoreAudio, it works well. Do I need to require or something? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with a similar problem.

Comment: @Pete Seems I did, I will test it later then update this question.

Comment: @simsicon I might have run into the same problem, would be grateful to hear your findings and solution!

Comment: I, too, am having the same issue and would be curious to hear the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding AudioToolbox to your frameworks probably is loading the toolkit, unless you're seeing errors during the build. You don't need to require anything else.

I have a RubyMotion program that calls AudioToolbox functions like `AudioFileOpenURL` and `AudioFileGetProperty` without error. Since AudioFileID is a struct, I don't think it is defined as a bare constant to use. If you are getting errors when using AudioToolbox functions, please update this question or perhaps start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket on RubyMotion bug tracker and tinkered with this issue for 3 days by myself, here is what I found

you have to patch AudioToolbox.bridgesupport for each iOS version you're targeting `(/Library/RubyMotion/data/ios/6.1/BridgeSupport/AudioToolbox.bridgesupport)` until this issue is fixed in upcoming RubyMotion release

Replace this line
`<cftype type='^{OpaqueAudioFileID=}' name='AudioFileID'/>`

with
`<opaque type='^{OpaqueAudioFileID=}' name='AudioFileID'/>`

this way **RubyMotion** won't treat **AudioFileID** as a structure defined somewhere (hence uninitialized constant error) and you'll be able to instantiate a pointer to AudioFileID by calling `Pointer.new AudioFileID.type`

Comment: Thanks, I didnt try but looks like make sense!

Answer (score 0):

To use the symbols from the AudioToolbox framework, you need to explicitly require them in your Ruby code. In this case, you should require the 'audio_toolbox' gem in your view controller file before using the symbols from the framework. Here's an example:

```
require 'audio_toolbox'

class RecorderViewController < UIViewController
  def your_method_name
    p AudioFileID
  end
end
```

Make sure you have the 'audio_toolbox' gem installed in your project. You can add it to your Gemfile if you haven't done so already:

```
gem 'audio_toolbox'
```